# Unclear of type of relationship to use

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have two tables, person and country.

Country is a table with all the countries, e.g. "Singapore", "America". While person is a table with all the users, storing their names, and country of residence etc.

The database table looks like this:

```
person
person_id int PK
name varchar(20)
country_id int FK

country
country_id int PK
country varchar(20)
```

I am trying to come up with a class diagram that looks like this: However, i am unclear of what relationship should i indicate for the variable Country inside of the Person class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name=person)
class Person{
    @Id
    @Column(name="person_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GeneratedType.IDENTITY)
    private int personId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ ?
    private Country country;

    // Accessor and Mutator
}

@Entity
@Table(name=country)
private Country{
    @Id
    @Column(name=country_id)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GeneratedType.IDENTITY)
    private int countryId;

    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;

    // Accessor and Mutator
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Person should contain the foreign key of Country.

This creates the relationship that a Person belongs to one (residential) country, while a country can have (of course) more Persons belonging to it. This is called a many-to-one relationship (if viewed from Country).

Comment: you mean person class should have a simple attribute representing the pk of country?